# Moving website from expired domain to an active subdomain

Tags: subdomains, domain

I had a website which it’s domain is expired: https://mrafiee.net
I also have another active domain and website: https://rafiee.net

I have created a subdomain under my active domain: https://old.rafiee.net
I copied all content in mrafiee.net foolder (which is an add-on domain in my cpanel) in my host, to old.rafiee.net folder.

I expected to reach my website when I go to https://old.rafiee.net, but it redirects me to https://mrafiee.net which is already expired.

I would be very grateful if someone can help me to solve this issue.
Thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the database stores information about the old domain.

Open the database in **phpmyadmin** and run this query. The code will replace the old domain with the new one.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'https://mrafiee.net', 'https://old.rafiee.net') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'https://mrafiee.net','https://old.rafiee.net');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://mrafiee.net', 'https://old.rafiee.net');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'https://mrafiee.net','https://old.rafiee.net');
```